How do I measure the SQL Database responsiveness
I am load testing my web app which is Azure App Server + Azure SQL Database.
I am looking at the the Azure data dashboard metrics as we load test it and most measures (DTU percentage, CPU percentage, etc.) average around 0.2% to 0.5% spiking to 2% at times.
On the query performance insight the worst one is 1.080 seconds, one at 0.860 seconds, and the rest under 0.5 seconds. All of my web pages of interest have either 1 or 2 queries although Entity Frameworks can break 1 query into several.
Performance recommendations and Automatic tuning have no suggestions. I'm 99.9% confident that I am indexing everything I should.
So here are my questions:

What else should I measure? The biggie I think is how long does a query wait to be executed. If a query is 0.0001 seconds to run, but it comes after the 1 second query, then it's 1.0001 before it returns. Is this worth looking at? And if so, where/how do I find this?
I think my queries are reduced to what I truly need. The ones that take time are a model that has 4 collections that are populated via a join table. And I need those 4 collections (I do not read other collections in the model I don't need). Is there anything I can do to speed up the the two over 0.5 second queries? When I've looked at it in the past a simple read it in query is no faster being in a stored procedure (and doing that then loses the Entity Framework advantages).


For performance tuning questions please provide the execution plans of the queries in question via Paste The Plan and ideally the table and index definitions of those involved in the query.

@J.D. My question #2 was inartful. My question is - is there anything I should look at doing to speed up queries, outside of the query itself. TIA

There's no generic or one size fits all answer. It just depends on the specifics of your setup which usually boils down to what I requested above. The 4 main things one can look at for performance tuning are: 1. Query Tuning, 2. Index Tuning, 3. System Re-architecting, 4. Hardware Provisioning. Most times it's #1 and #2 which are explainable by the information I requested above. #3 is as well. And if none of those, process of elimination leaves you #4 which is pretty uncommon to be the solution to the problem.

@J.D. Thank you. I have fine-tuned the queries already so I think I'm now in the "it is what it is" situation. thanks

Eh, 500ms could be a long time for a query to execute depending on its complexity and how much data it's processing/returning, or perhaps it's acceptable in your situation. No way to know without seeing it. For reference, I could return data from a 1 trillion row table in less time than that.

IMO, it is all about prioritizing your queries and hard work. I have cases where a normal exec time for a query is 0.4 ms, and when it gest a different plan that takes it to say 20 ms the system more or less halts and becomes un-usable. The hard work is collecting intel and then tune your important queries (and have them stable when it comes to plans).

check your wait statistics - if the db engine is waiting then you have an idea what to optimize

@StephenMorris-Mo64 thank you - this is a big help.

FWIW, there's always wait stats, even when nothing's running, so the presence of them doesn't necessarily mean there's a problem. But it can help point you in the right direction at times. Particularly if you're looking at them for a given query (though at that point the execution plan is going to be the most telling piece of information anyway). If you want to get a general health overview of your server's issues then look into running tools like the First Responder Kit and sp_WhoIsActive.

@J.D. Thank you - I'm going to use the First Responder Kit.

-- Identify long-running queries and wait times
SELECT 
    qs.sql_handle,
    qs.statement_start_offset,
    qs.statement_end_offset,
    qs.execution_count,
    qs.total_worker_time,
    qs.total_elapsed_time,
    qs.total_logical_reads,
    qs.total_physical_reads,
    qs.total_logical_writes,
    qs.wait_time,
    q.text
FROM 
    sys.dm_exec_query_stats qs
CROSS APPLY 
    sys.dm_exec_sql_text(qs.sql_handle) q
ORDER BY 
    qs.total_elapsed_time DESC;

-- Rebuild fragmented indexes
ALTER INDEX ALL ON [dbo].[YourTableName] REBUILD;

-- Update statistics
UPDATE STATISTICS [dbo].[YourTableName];

-- Check missing indexes
SELECT 
    migs.avg_total_user_cost * (migs.avg_user_impact * 0.01) * (migs.user_seeks + migs.user_scans) AS improvement_measure,
    'CREATE INDEX IX_' + LEFT(p.name, 32) + '_' + LEFT(o.name, 32) + ' ON ' + p.name + '.' + o.name + ' (' + 
    ISNULL(mid.equality_columns,'') +
    CASE WHEN mid.equality_columns IS NOT NULL AND mid.inequality_columns IS NOT NULL THEN ',' ELSE '' END +
    ISNULL(mid.inequality_columns, '') + ')' +
    ISNULL(' INCLUDE (' + mid.included_columns + ')', '') AS create_index_statement
FROM 
    sys.dm_db_missing_index_groups mig
    INNER JOIN sys.dm_db_missing_index_group_stats migs ON migs.group_handle = mig.index_group_handle
    INNER JOIN sys.dm_db_missing_index_details mid ON mig.index_handle = mid.index_handle
    INNER JOIN sys.objects o ON mid.object_id = o.object_id
    INNER JOIN sys.schemas s ON o.schema_id = s.schema_id
    INNER JOIN sys.databases p ON p.database_id = mid.database_id
ORDER BY 
    improvement_measure DESC;

-- Enable execution plan
SET SHOWPLAN_XML ON;

-- Run your query to get the execution plan
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[YourTableName] WHERE [Condition];

-- Disable execution plan
SET SHOWPLAN_XML OFF;

